# How to Get Updated row Id in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mongodb, hibernate

```
    Query branch_update = null;
    Branches branchObject = null;
    try {
        branch_update = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("Update Branches set branchname =:branchname,update_date =:update_date WHERE branchname =:branchname1");
        branch_update.setParameter("branchname", stringCellValue);
        branch_update.setParameter("update_date", new Date());
        branch_update.setParameter("branchname1", stringCellValue);
        int update_id = branch_update.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.error("Exception occured at \t e", exception.getMessage(), exception);
    }
```

while updating the row using branch name. how to get updated row branch_id ?

thanks in advance...

Comment: are you using auto_increment for branch_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getGeneratedKeys() method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-last-insert-id.html) to get resultset

```
 s.execute();  // perform the UPDATE
    try (ResultSet rs = s.getGeneratedKeys()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));  // print the "branch_id" value of the updated row
        }
    }
```

EDIT:-
In that case i think this should help

```
Iterator iterator = branch_update.list().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Branches branch = (Branches) iterator.next();
            }
```

Comment: I don't think it would work here: its purpose is to retrieve the keys generated during an insert

Comment: i am using Hibernet sessionFactory  "sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("")"  i am unable to get getGeneratedKeys()..